# Transfer file from kubernetes cluster to other ec2 machine

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have a pod in a Kubernetes(k8s) which has a Java application running on it in a docker container. This application produces logs. I want to move these log files to another amazon EC2 machine. Both the machines are linux based. How can this be done. Is it possible to do so using simple `scp` command?

Answer (score 1):

To copy a file from a pod to a machine via scp you can use the following command:

```
kubectl cp <namespace>/<pod>:/path/inside/container /path/on/your/host
```

Answer (score 1):

For moving logs from pods to your log store , you can use the following options to do it all the time for you , instead of one time copy:

- filebeat
- fluentd
- fluentbit

https://github.com/fluent/fluent-bit-kubernetes-logging

https://docs.fluentd.org/v0.12/articles/kubernetes-fluentd

Comment: Seems helpful. I have some comments from above , and will experiment this as well aling with those.

Comment: @mohdshoaib im already using fluentbit and it works perfectly

Comment: I am trying fluentd now, and installed it using td-agent package. But when I am trying to start fluentd it gives me error saying there is some error in config file. My config is:
`<source>
  @type tail
  path /var/log/test-fluent/testfile.log
  tag foo.*
  <parse>
    @type none
  </parse>
</source>

<match **>
 @type stdout
</match>`

Answer (score 0):

You can copy file(s) from a Kubernetes Container by using the `kubectl cp` command.

Example:

`kubectl cp <mypodname>:/var/log/syslog .`

Comment: My concern is to transfer the file to a toally different machine. Is there any option in `kubectl` command to do so?

Comment: `kubectl cp` isn't concerned about other "machines" so to speak.. it is a crude way to simply copy a file. I would `kubectl cp ..` then run your `scp ..` command (or whatever) afterwards. You _could_ `cat` the file and then redirect the output to another command. If you have a lot of files for instance, you could use rsync or something of the like within the container itself.

Comment: On another note, if this pertains to log acquisition I would use a logging driver or something similar that will _collect_ the logs for you and write it to an ELK stack.

Comment: thanks @yomateo, I will test it and shall update the thread here